# I live in the Northeast area of the US, and my emergency heat on my furnace/ac is broken. Can I get thru the winter months without fixing it?

Tags: hvac, furnace, air-conditioning, central-heating, heat-pump

I live in the Northeast area of the US, and my ***emergency heat*** on my furnace/ac is broken. Can I get thru the winter months without fixing it?

Comment: That depends on (a) what the heat-pump does if it gets really cold and there is no emergency heat (i.e., does it do nothing at all or does it produce "some heat but not enough") and (b) how cold it gets. (b) most definitely varies year to year, but on average Washington, DC is quite different from Boston.

Comment: Electric, gas or oil?

Comment: @LeeSam The unit runs on electric

Comment: Yes, no, maybe. What else can we say? We don’t know exactly how the weather will be. We don’t know how well your house is built - construction quality, insulation etc. vtc.

Comment: I live in Maryland in a townhouse.

Comment: Make/model/size of heat pump?

Comment: Some people don't mind if the house is a little chilly, others like a tropical beach inside all year 'round. We don't know what kind of person you are, so we can only offer an opinion, so it's hard for us to say...

Comment: Have you ever heard of "Murphy's Law".  Are you capable of fixing it yourself?  Do you know exactly why it's broken?  If you answered "yes"  to all the above, fix it now or at least get the necessary parts.

Comment: Are you concerned about maintaining setpoint, or simply about freezeups until you can get a tech in?  Also, what make/model is your heat pump's outdoor unit?

Comment: Absolutely. Install multiple Cadet heaters, which are permanently installed baseboard heaters. They look respectable, won't hurt resale, last 40 years, and best of all, *they're dirt cheap*.  You can either put thermostats on them individually, or use an appropriate relay to have them turn on when the main thermostat calls for emergency heat.

Answer (score 1):

I would call in an HVAC company that is versed in heat pump repair. Since we do not know what is wrong with the electric back up heat we can only guess. The problem may be as simple as a bad sequencing relay, broken or loose wire, or a bad heat strip. Instead of being cold, I would get it serviced.